# TOR routing on same machine as browser

Tags: linux, proxy

I want apps like Firefox and Chrome to have their Internet traffic routed through TOR, such that Firefox and Chrome would not know they are going through TOR. How would I configure Linux to make that happen?
I do not want to use tor browser, in fact I can't as I use ARM Linux.

Comment: The search term you're probably looking for is "transparent proxy". There are many blog posts and questions on [this site](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparent-proxy) about this that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, well there are a few methods I have heard of:

- If you have Proxychains installed on your distro, then messing with the .conf file for your proxy settings can allow your whole machines traffic to run through Tor (I would explain how to do it if I could but I've never done it myself) For this I think using your package manager should work for the install.
- Nipe, which is a tool that also routes your machine traffic through Tor. Use `git clone https://github.com/GouveaHeitor/nipe` will install it.

If I could exemplify the difference between them I would but I have no personal experience with these tools.
https://github.com/GouveaHeitor/nipe
https://linuxhint.com/proxychains-tutorial/
One potential issue is that these do not just Torify your browser traffic, but the whole machines. I don't know about you but this could either be a bonus or downside.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily, follow me

> first check if the tor service is installed, type `service tor status`  in terminal if it is installed something would show up, if not then install it by`sudo apt-get install tor`  in terminal.

> After installation, we have to configure proxychains, type command `nano /etc/proxychains.conf` it will open the configuration file.

> Remove the # from "Dynamic chain" .
> Add # before "strict chain" and "random chain".
> Remove # from "proxy dns".
> write socks5 127.0.0.1 9050 in last line of proxy list.

Now save the configuration file by pressing ctrl+o and enter.
To start using proxychains you need to restart the tor service type `service tor restart` in terminal.

*Now you can use the proxychain service by typing proxychains before the application you want to run.
Ex> proxychains firefox [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or just firefox.[image: here is the screenshot of adding soc5 in the proxy chains]

[image: removing # from Dynamic]